# Fast accessing pixel values of jpeg images

Tags: c++, image-processing, jpeg, computer-vision

CompVision once again, I'm working with jpeg images in my application. Just because I'm a bit familiar with `MFC` and `ATL`, I used `CImage` to access pixel values.

For my needs I calculate brightness matrix for the image during initialization. Function goes like this (`Image` is the name of my own class, unimportant, bright is float[][]):

```
 void Image::fillBrightnessMatrix(){
    COLORREF val;
    for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<height;j++){
          val=src.GetPixel(i,j);
              bright[i][j]=rgb_to_L(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Where src is an instance of `CImage` class, rgb_to_L - some function that calculates brightness of the color.

Examining the performance of my app, I discovered that `GetPixel` is the most expensive operation, and it significantly (really, ~700 times slower than any other operation) slows down the whole initializing of image. **The question is, which library can you suggest for fast access to single pixel values**? I don't need any other operations but loading jpeg image and accessing single pixels. Performance is important, because my application works with set of ~3000 images and I can't wait for hours to get results.

Comment: If you just decode the DC values of the MCU's in the JPEG bitstream, you don't even need to do a (very) expensive iDCT to work out the pixel values - the DC is the average YCbCr value of the entire MCU, which you can sum/average over the image instead of every pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CBitmap::GetBits() to get a raw pointer to the pixel data.  You can now directly party on the pixels without going through the expensive GetPixel() method.  There are a number of things you need to be careful with when you do this:

- You have to use CBitmap::GetPitch() to calculate the offset to the start of a line.  The pitch is not the same as the width.
- Lines in the bitmap are stored upside-down
- You have to deal with the pixel format yourself.  A 24bpp image stores 3 bytes per pixel.  An indexed format like 8bpp requires looking up the color in the color table.  32bpp is the easy one, 4 bytes per pixel and the pitch is always the same as the width.

Comment: Damn, i knew there must be something better than GetPixel! Thanks. Now i have to find a working example of using this methods, cuz the whole web is filled with messages from noobs like me asking why dont their snippets work.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

This is a humble code snippet to get you started:

```
IplImage* pRGBImg = cvLoadImage("c:\\test.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); 
if (!pRGBImg)
{
  std::cout << "!!! cvLoadImage failed !!!" << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

int width = pRGBImg->width; 
int height = pRGBImg->height;
int bpp = pRGBImg->nChannels; 
for (int i=0; i < width*height*bpp; i+=bpp) 
{
  if (!(i % (width*bpp))) // print empty line for better readability
      std::cout << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::dec << "R:" << (int) pRGBImg->imageData[i] <<  
                          " G:" << (int) pRGBImg->imageData[i+1] <<  
                          " B:" << (int) pRGBImg->imageData[i+2] << " "; 
}
```

Comment: I cant use OpenCV. Frankly, i dont want to use it. It's to heavy and too compilcated for the task im talking about.

Comment: @Anton You could have stated that you didn't like OpenCV on your question. OpenCV is used even on the iPhone, so I don't know what heavy actually means to you. As my code above shows, OpenCV is not complicated at all. But I think that's a matter of experience. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably extract the jpeg to raw data, then access the raw data instead of GetPixel.

Comment: I believe its the best way to solve my problem, all i want is the exact name of library that programmers have been using and can advise :)